# Convert a Resource Image into Image Brush - c#

Tags: c#, image, brush

i want to change in runtime the Background property and i have to set an ImageBrush for it.
I have added some images as Resources on my project, and now i can use them as System.Drawing.Bitmap.

How can i convert System.Drawing.Bitmap into ImageBrush ?

Comment: Are you using databinding (possibly with MVVM) or do you want to attach it in the codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the codebehind to set it, you can do it like this:

```
BitmapImage img; 

// get bitmapimage from resources and assign to img

ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = img;

myControl.Background = brush;
```

If you are using databinding you'd need to implement a ValueConverter

Answer (score 0):

From [How to create ImageBrush from System.Drawing.Image in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490599/how-to-create-imagebrush-from-system-drawing-image-in-wpf):

```
var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                                                         IntPtr.Zero,
                                                         Int32Rect.Empty,
                                                         BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
        );
bitmap.Dispose();
var brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapSource);
```

"This solution, however, doesnt free the memory of the handle. For information on how to remove the memory leak see [WPF CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap() memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak)"