# WPF cannot implicitly convert system.drawing.bitmap to media.brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the background of a button manually in my WPF app.

I have an image imported into my resources and I want to do:

```
MyButton.Background = MyProject.Properties.Resources.myImage;
```

But I get the error:

> cannot implicitly convert system.drawing.bitmap to media.brush

How can I do this??

Comment: Background is the wrong property, you need something like BackgroundImage

Comment: @CSharpie you're wrong, `Background` is the right property. You need to set it to an `ImageBrush`.

Comment: Oh ok. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should read about brushes first [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And then use `ImageBrush`, something like this:

```
MyButton.Background = new ImageBrush(...);
```

(or, maybe, put the brush into resources...)

**UPDATE**

You can find how to create imageSource from bitmap easilly. for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491098/1300049). Like:

```
var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(MyProject.Properties.Resources.myImage.GetHbitmap(),
                                  IntPtr.Zero,
                                  Int32Rect.Empty,
                                  BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
MyButton.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmapSource);
```

Comment: This will not work, as `myImage` is of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Comment: I`ve added one of the ways to transform bitmap to source

Answer (score 5):

In a WPF application, you do usually not add image resources as you did in WinForms.

Instead you add the image file directly to your Visual Studio project, just like any other file. If there are multiple images, it may make sense to put them in a subfolder of the project (e.g. called "images"). The `Build Action` of that file has to be set to `Resource` (which is the default for image files).

Now you can create a `BitmapImage` from a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to that file.

Finally you create an `ImageBrush` from the `BitmapImage` to set the `Background` property.

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/myImage.jpg");
var image = new BitmapImage(uri);
MyButton.Background = new ImageBrush(image);
```