# WPF CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap memory leaks

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-leaks

so ive been having a bit of a memory leak problem with my C# code, I have searched fairly thoroughly and do realize there is another question here [WPF CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap() memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak) (and many others) that sort of cover the same topic but doesnt meet my criteria or solve my problem.

So here is my code, I got this from another project a while back
Im fairly positive that the problem has to do with `// Here's the WPF glue to make it all work. It converts from an 
                // hBitmap to a BitmapSource. Love the WPF interop functions
                bitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    compatibleBitmapHandle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());`

Here is the full method code, this is being called like this and

`BitmapSource captured = CaptureRegion(
                hWnd,
                rect.X,
                rect.Y,
                rect.Width,
                rect.Height, 
                true);`

And is also being called many times per second.(70-100ms per call)

```
      // capture a region of a the screen, defined by the hWnd
        public static BitmapSource CaptureRegion(
            IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool addToClipboard)
        {
            IntPtr sourceDC = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr targetDC = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr compatibleBitmapHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            BitmapSource bitmap = null;
            //IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
//            IntPtr hBitmap;

            try
            {
                // gets the main desktop and all open windows
                sourceDC = User32.GetDC(User32.GetDesktopWindow());

                //sourceDC = User32.GetDC(hWnd);
                targetDC = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(sourceDC);

                // create a bitmap compatible with our target DC
                compatibleBitmapHandle = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(sourceDC, width, height);

                // gets the bitmap into the target device context
                Gdi32.SelectObject(targetDC, compatibleBitmapHandle);

                // copy from source to destination
                Gdi32.BitBlt(targetDC, 0, 0, width, height, sourceDC, x, y, Gdi32.SRCCOPY);

                // Here's the WPF glue to make it all work. It converts from an 
                // hBitmap to a BitmapSource. Love the WPF interop functions
                bitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    compatibleBitmapHandle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ScreenCaptureException(string.Format("Error capturing region {0},{1},{2},{3}", x, y, width, height), ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Gdi32.DeleteObject(compatibleBitmapHandle);
                // Gdi32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                User32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, sourceDC);
                User32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, targetDC);
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
```

I really cant understand how I can apply the fix mentioned in the above thread to my problem, because my BitmapSource doesnt seem to be created from a bitmap, I cant see how deleting the bitmap object can help.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is it a GDI handle leak or a memory leak? (You can check with Windows Task Manager whether the number of GDI objects increases).

Comment: Well I just checked and it appears that the GDI objects goes up from about 37 to 1400 in a couple of seconds, does this mean its not CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me; I cannot see that you are leaking any GDI handles there. Try to find other places in your code where it allocates GDI handles (bitmaps, fonts, brushes, etc.). Or use a tool like [AQTime](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling) to find resource leaks.

Comment: for GDI leaks I usually use Deleaker...