# Exception “A generic error occurred in GDI+" occurs in Bitmap.Save

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

In our application we have a problem with an **ExternalException in GDI+**.
The application is distributed and runs on over 100 computers successfully and we cannot reproduce it in our test environment. However one single computer crashes with the mentioned exception.

The `Bitmap` was previously loaded via a resx file and the `BitmapImage` is used in a WPF part of the application just for displaying.

Here's the corresponding code:

```
private static BitmapImage ConvertToImage(Bitmap bitmap)
      {
         var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
         using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
         {
            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
            memory.Position = 0;

            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
         }

         return bitmapImage;
      }
```

The application crashes when calling

```
bitmap.Save
```

The computer has **Windows 7 x64** installed with **.NET 4.0**.

Any hints on what this could be?

**EDIT 1:**

I didn't find out so far what's causing the exception. We found out that the exception only happens with some specific images. But all images are in the `PNG` format.

For now we will stick to the solution of using `CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` which is working for us. [CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap - Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546121/1108036)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you combining GDI+ with WPF?

Comment: The main part of the application is Winforms. There's a small part which is WPF and uses the same Resources.

Comment: My only guess could be that the bitmap is too large and/or the available memory is too small.

Comment: The thing is that I've run into "generic" errors from GDI+ before, and almost each time it's for a different reason; so, even if you can recreate the error, you may not have tapped into the source of the error on that one machine.

Comment: The image size is around 32*32 pixel. -> Very small. Do you know any methods to find out more about the error?

Comment: Just for anyone seeing this later.. if it crashes on `bitmap.Save` then the image object is _already corrupted_ at that moment. It is completely unrelated to the shown code.