# WPF: Way to take screenshots

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

Looking to modify the following to take a screenshot off all monitors. I have tried adapting it but my images are blank. Writing it to test.png is for testing. The `byte[]` will be sent to the receiving app.

```
public byte[] Take()
{
    int screenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth);
    int screenHeight = Convert.ToInt32(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);
    int screenLeft = Convert.ToInt32(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft);
    int screenTop = Convert.ToInt32(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenTop);

    RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush();

    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

    using (drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.PushTransform(new ScaleTransform(1, 1));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(screenWidth, screenHeight)));
    }
    renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

    PngBitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

    Byte[] _imageArray;

    using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pngEncoder.Save(outputStream);
        _imageArray = outputStream.ToArray();
    }

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\test.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(_imageArray);
        }
    }

    return _imageArray;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you'll need to add references for the following namespaces:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then enumerate your monitors to get the bounding rectangle for all display surfaces and pass that in to the `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` method call:

```
private static BitmapSource CopyScreen()
{
    var left = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.X);
    var top = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.Y);
    var right = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width);
    var bottom = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height);
    var width = right - left;
    var height = bottom - top;

    using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
        {
            bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                screenBmp.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind though that monitors often don't fit neatly into a single rectangle, particularly if they have different resolution etc, so you might be better snap-shotting the individual screens. Either way, the solution to your problem is to change the coordinates that you were passing in to the `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` method call.

EDIT: see Demetris Leptos's comment below, the code I've posted in this answer should be calling DeleteObject on the bitmap returned by `screenBmp.GetHbitmap()` so as to avoid a memory leak, as specified in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: is there a way to grab each screen as separate capture

Comment: Absolutely, just enumerate each screen and pass the rectangle {Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, Bounds.X+Bounds.Width, Bounds.Y+Bounds.Height} in as the source rectangle. If you look at the first 4 lines of my code above you'll see I was just creating a rectangle that bounded all of them.

Comment: Isn't there a way without using Windows.Forms? I might as well not use WPF if I have to use Windows.Forms as a reference.

Comment: @McoreD no, WPF is used for the _presentation_ of graphics, hence the 'P'. It also uses the DirectX API, which is separate to the GDI API that forms the core interface to the Windows rendering subsystem.

Comment: possible memory leak - posting before I forget to and get lost back into the code:

// your code
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1000, 1000)) 
{
    IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap(); 

    try 
    {
        var source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally 
    {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap)
    }
}

from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak

Comment: Yeah can't accept an answer that requires a reference to WinForms when the question is asking for WPF

Comment: @PandaWood WPF is a _presentation_ framework used by individual applications, why would you try to use it to capture the entire Windows desktop, which for most versions of Windows is still based on GDI? Just because WPF provides an alternative/better presentation framework doesn't mean it has replaced WinForms and GDI altogether. The only reason to do anything like this would be to then display that background in a WPF window, but irrespective of which exact technique you use you'd still have to essentially capture it with GDI first and then upload it into a WPF/DirectX texture for display.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Thanks, I see your point. And I shouldn't be religously trying to avoid including GDI-based (winforms) libraries - especially if that's the only thing that can do the job

Answer (score 0):

Just to collate the above answers and comments into a single static class with all the includes and imports needed.
Tried it with memory profiler and didn't see any leaks.

Use with `BitmapSource bmpSource = ScreenCapture.GetBitmapSource();`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows;

namespace GraphicUtils
{

    public static class ScreenCapture
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        public static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource()
        {
            BitmapSource result = null;
            var left = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.X);
            var top = Screen.AllScreens.Min(screen => screen.Bounds.Y);
            var right = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.X + screen.Bounds.Width);
            var bottom = Screen.AllScreens.Max(screen => screen.Bounds.Y + screen.Bounds.Height);
            var width = right - left;
            var height = bottom - top;

            using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                using (var bmpGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
                {
                    bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
                    IntPtr hBitmap = screenBmp.GetHbitmap();
                    try
                    {
                        result = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                                            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                                            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```