# How to capture screen in .NET

Tags: c#, screen-capture

Is there any managed API (C#) I can use to make screen captures, similar to what fraps does? Some possible things I'd like to do with it:

1. Capture the whole screen (basic).
2. Screen capture of full screen application.
3. Screen capture of currently active window.
4. Capture video of screen.

Comment: try here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5049122/1726419
http://stackoverflow.com/q/362986/1726419

Comment: And my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338960/wpf-way-to-take-screenshots).

Comment: So basically WinForms.