# Memory Leak after for loop when displaying previous draw line in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

When I am drawing line and then iterate in for loop it cause high memory leak then after several line it crashed.

```
private Pen ReDrawFromGrid(Pen pen)
    {
        for (int parseDgV = 0; parseDgV < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; parseDgV++)
        {
            float redrawX1;
            float redrawY1;
            float redrawX2;
            float redrawY2;
            float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out redrawX1);
            float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out redrawY1);
            float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out redrawX2);
            float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out redrawY2);
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Solid")
            {
                dashRedraw = new float[1] { 10 };
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Dash")
            {
                dashRedraw = new float[2] { 10, 10 };
            }
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Dot")
            {
                dashRedraw = new float[2] { 3, 5 };
            }
            else
            {
                dashRedraw = new float[1] { 10 };
            }
            pen = new Pen(dataGridView1.Rows[parseDgV].Cells[4].Style.BackColor);
            pen.DashPattern = dashRedraw;
            g.DrawLine(pen, redrawX1, redrawY1, redrawX2, redrawY2);
            this.Refresh();
            this.axDNVideoX1.Invalidate();
        }
        GC.Collect();
        return pen;
    }
```

I tried to put dispose before and after in this for loop but it resulted no line drawn. How can I iterate draw line without causing memory leak?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where/how is your `g` defined?

Comment: I use it as a Graphics.FromImage in mousemove because axDNVideoX1 dll file doesn't support on paint.. btw, I'm using live camera, drawn lines are for putting the limits.

Comment: Is this getting called recursively?  The `this.Refresh()` call in the inner loop of a drawing method... looks like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Already remove this.Refresh() but leak still persist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick re-write of the basic drawing code with some minor tweaks:

```
static float[] patSolid = new float[] { 10 };
static float[] patDash = new float[] { 10, 10 };
static float[] patDot = new float[] { 3, 5 };

private void RedrawFromGrid(Graphics g)
{
    float X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var cells = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells;

        if (!float.TryParse(cells[0].Value.ToString(), out X1) ||
            !float.TryParse(cells[1].Value.ToString(), out Y1) ||
            !float.TryParse(cells[2].Value.ToString(), out X2) ||
            !float.TryParse(cells[2].Value.ToString(), out Y2)
        )
            continue;

        var style = cells[5].Value.ToString();
        float[] pattern = patSolid;
        if (style == "Dash")
            pattern = patDash;
        else if (style == "Dot")
            pattern = patDot;

        using (var pen = new Pen(cells[4].Style.BackColor))
        {
            pen.DashPattern = pattern;
            g.DrawLine(pen, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit dirty still, since I wanted to keep the basic functionality close to where you had it.

A few refinements:

The only thing that needs to be allocated inside the loop is the `pen` object, and you could get rid of that too by caching the pens and reusing them.  But since we're doing allocation each time, the `pen` needs to be disposed of when you're done with it.  The `using` statement does this for you.  You should be doing the same for the `Graphics` object in the method that calls this.

Second: don't allocate the same arrays over and over, allocate them once and reuse them.  You already know ahead of time what patterns you are going to be using, so pre-allocating the pattern arrays is a good idea.  Especially if this is getting called 30 times per second by your video code or similar.

And finally, this method should have as few side effects as possible.  The method that calls it should take care of the side effects - calling `this.Refresh()` or `this.axDNVideoX1.Invalidate()` *after* disposing of the `Graphics` object when all the drawing is done.

In general a drawing operation should be as fast - and have as few side effects - as it is possible to make it.  Allocating arrays, calling `Invalidate` or `Refresh`, etc. are for the caller to do.  Don't let your drawing method do anything but *draw*.

---

edit:

Incidentally, calling `GC.Collect()` will not solve a memory leak.  In fact it's quite likely that it's not going to do anything at all in this context, since none of the allocations happening inside this loop will have reached termination anyway.  When you find yourself directly invoking the garbage collector it is almost always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First, the parameter "pen" does not have sense to me. You are passing a Pen to your method and then in your method you are creating a new instance of the Pen and then you are returning a Pen. I would cache all required Pen instances and reuse them. Once you don't need a particular Pen any more, Dispose it.

The only 'Memory leak' worrying part of the code here that I see is a 'axDNVideoX1' which is it seems an ActiveX control and it has to do something with Video. Try to comment out that part of the code and see if you still have a memory leak.

I would not say that the 'DrawLine' causes a memory leak.

Keep your eye on the count of the 'GDI objects' created and destroyed. You can see this value in the Task Manager.

Comment: I already remove axDNVIdeoX1 and dispose pen but the leak still persist. Thanks

Comment: @JeffreyOrcena: are you certainly sure that this method is causing you a memory leak? Try to comment out all the code from that method.

Comment: hi sir thanks! I found out what cause memory leak but I don't know how to dispose it..                                              IntPtr bh = b.GetHbitmap();
axDNVideoX1.SetBitmapOverlay((int)bh, 0, 0, 0xffffff, 255);
if (oldbh != (IntPtr)0) DeleteObject(oldbh);

Comment: @JeffreyOrcena: You need to call DeleteObject(...) on your hBitmap. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `Pen` per loop iteration. You need to dispose those objects properly. The pen you pass to the function is lost, the pens you create in the loop are lost except for the last which is returned.

`using` blocks are your friend. Use them.