# WPF Image: .Source = Clipboard.GetImage() is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, interopbitmapimage

This simple program does not work, the image does not appear in the Window.

```
namespace ClipBoardTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                ImageUIElement.Source = Clipboard.GetImage();
                Console.WriteLine("Clipboard copied to UIElement");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No image in Clipboard");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Output is "Clipboard copied to UIElement", but the image does not appear in the Window.

XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="ClipBoardTest.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
         <Button x:Name="CopyButton" Content="Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="CopyButton_Click"/>
         <Image x:Name="ImageUIElement" Margin="90,10,10,10"/>
     </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Is there anybody, who understands, what is wrong?

Comment: Try the workaround as specified [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10589cd6-6a48-4497-8f7d-a12490f376c6/clipboardgetimage-and-imagesource).

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior too, but oddly just with **some** images on the clipboard. Images copied from the browser work for me. Images copied from SnagIt for some reason don't even though I can capture and save that same image explicitly to disk and use it. One alternate workaround for me has been to save to disk first then load it from there to display in the control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`Clipboard.GetDataObject`** to get bitmap and convert it into bitmapSource. Also, be aware that **`Bitmap.GetHbitmap()`** leaks memory unless you call DeleteObject on it.

So, correct solution would be to dispose the IntPtr after use. Declare the method at class level and use it from your code:

```
// at class level
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

---

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    IDataObject clipboardData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (clipboardData != null)
    {
        if (clipboardData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)clipboardData.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap);
            IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            try
            {
                ImageUIElement.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                Console.WriteLine("Clipboard copied to UIElement");
            }
            finally 
            {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source - [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10589cd6-6a48-4497-8f7d-a12490f376c6/clipboardgetimage-and-imagesource) and [Memory leak in Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546121/632337).

Comment: Thank you. If I don´t need System.Windows.Forms for other purposes, this is better than the workaround at social.msdn.microsoft.com. Thanks. :-)

Comment: bmp.GetHbitmap() should be bitmap.GetHbitmap()

Comment: @ChrisZeh - Yeah a small typo. Corrected. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: Note: at line 3, `Clipboard` refers to `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`, not `System.Windows.Clipboard`.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2019, WPF C# project targeting .NET Core 3.1, the following works (or, at least, it does for me):

```
myImage.Source = GetImageFromClipBoard();
```

where:

```
public static ImageSource GetImageFromClipBoard ()
        {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
            return Clipboard.GetImage();
            }
        else
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for all copied bitmaps. For example if a bitmap is copied in Microsoft's Paint it gets an empty area but if it the bitmap is copied in Paint.NET, LibreOffice or such it works. Generally the problem is that some programs like Microsoft's Paint copy only a device dependent bitmap and WPF likes to work with device INdependent bitmaps. You will have to convert it by adding a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure as shown in this blog: https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/

Comment: For anyone needing to get the image from paint, highly recommend the link attached in @AndresRohrAtlasInformatik comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works fine.

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    // ImageUIElement.Source = Clipboard.GetImage(); // does not work
    System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject clipboardData = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (clipboardData != null)
    {
        if (clipboardData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)clipboardData.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap);
            ImageUIElement.Source =  System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            Console.WriteLine("Clipboard copied to UIElement");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, a working and simple solution to the problem. Nice job.