# How to convert an image in a clipboard into a Stream in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

How can I retrieve an image copied in a clipboard into System.IO.Stream in C#?

```
Stream lStream = new MemoryStream();

IDataObject lIDataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (lIDataObj.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
{
  System.Drawing.Image lImage = (System.Drawing.Image)lIDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

  lImage.Save(lStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

  //this.RADRichTextBox.InsertImage(lStream, "jpg");
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Which part of your code doesn't work? Are you getting errors?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's what it says : _Impossible to cast an objet of type 'System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'._ <br/> on trying this line : **System.Drawing.Image lImage = (System.Drawing.Image)lIDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);**

Comment: Well, yes, the Clipboard doesn't contain a WPF image. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clipboard does not contain a WPF Image, but a Windows Forms Bitmap. So what you have to do is get the Windows Forms Bitmap first and *then* convert it to a WPF image.

An example for this can be found here: [WPF Image: .Source = Clipboard.GetImage() is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749843/wpf-image-source-clipboard-getimage-is-not-displayed)

Comment: The problem was solved by replacing _System.Windows.Clipboard_ **by** _System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard_

Comment: wondering why we even need System.Windows.Clipboard :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668469/system-drawing-image-to-stream-c-sharp) SO post, you have to modify the way you populate your stream by :

```
System.Drawing.Image lImage = (System.Drawing.Image)lIDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
lStream.Save(lImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Really? What did you just say? It doesn't work.