# Fast display of System.Drawing.Image in WPF Image

Tags: c#, wpf, system.drawing, bitmapimage

I need to convert webcam-picture (retrieved by AForge) to a `BitmapImage` in order to use it as a source for the WPF Image-control.

The following source is working but it runs with only like 5-7 FPS on a 3rd Gen i7.

**Are there better alternatives to improve the speed?**

```
    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        System.Drawing.Image img = eventArgs.Frame;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage;

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {

            img.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }

        bitmapImage.Freeze();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            outputImage.Source = bitmapImage;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: You may try [CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1546091/1136211).

Comment: There is no method `GetHBitmap()` for  `System.Drawing.Image`

Comment: It certainly is a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. Did you try to cast it?

Comment: Just checked it. `NewFrameEventArgs.Frame` is actually already declared as Bitmap. So change your variable declaration to `var img = eventArgs.Frame;`.

Comment: Anyway, the fastest way might be to (re-)use a single WriteableBitmap, like shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329047/1136211).

Comment: The solutin with the HBitmap gives me this exception `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll``

Comment: You should [Freeze](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) the BitmapSource before passing it the the BeginInvoke delegate. Or you move the whole conversion code to the BeginInvoke delegate. Hard to tell without seeing your code, or even a stack trace of the exception.