# Computer Vision Memory Leak Problem in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bitmap, computer-vision, emgucv

I am having a memory leak problem in this line of code for Computer Vision.

```
private static void UpdateResultingImage(bool onlyShowFace = false)
{
    //memory leaks happen in this method here
    if ((imageBitmap == null && faceBitmap == null) || ResultingImage == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (faceBitmap != null)
    {
        if (faceBitmapSource == null)
        {
            faceBitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(faceBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
           IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            faceBitmapSource = ScaleBitmap(faceBitmapSource, ResultingImage.Width, ResultingImage.Height);
        }

        else
        {
              // I think memory leak occurs each time I assign a new BitmapSource before disposing previous bitmap source 
             //I have tried BitmapSource?.Dispose() to stop memory leak but Dispose() does not exist in   BitmapSource class 
            faceBitmapSource = null;
            faceBitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(faceBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
           IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            faceBitmapSource = ScaleBitmap(faceBitmapSource, ResultingImage.Width, ResultingImage.Height);
        }
    }

    if (imageBitmap != null)
    {
        if (imageBitmapSource == null)
        {
            imageBitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(imageBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
           IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            imageBitmapSource = ScaleBitmap(imageBitmapSource, ResultingImage.Width, ResultingImage.Height);
        }

        else
        {
            // I think memory leak occurs each time I assign a new BitmapSource before disposing                         previous bitmap source 
            //I have tried BitmapSource?.Dispose() to stop memory leak but Dispose() does not exist in BitmapSource class 
            imageBitmapSource = null;
            imageBitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(imageBitmap.GetHbitmap(),
           IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            imageBitmapSource = ScaleBitmap(imageBitmapSource, ResultingImage.Width, ResultingImage.Height);

        }
    }

    if (!onlyShowFace)
    {
        ResultingImage.Source = imageBitmapSource;
        return;
    }


    ResultingImage.Source = faceBitmapSource;
}
```

I have tried disposing

I have tried using BitmapSource?.Dispose but the Dispose() does not exist in the BitmapSource class.
I have also tried setting BitmapSource to null, but to no avail
I have tried using GC.Collect() as well, but to no avail.
I'm currently out of ideas and will appreciate any help I get

Comment: Have you seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak

Comment: yes thank you so much
I've been stuck on this for about 2 hours :)